# Mapserver displays blank image of POINT layer data extracted from PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, mapserver

I am trying to display a couple of lat/long points with Mapserver, which are stored in a PostGIS database.

Here is my Database setup:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
 gid             SERIAL  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 geom            GEOMETRY(POINT) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (geom) VALUES ('POINT(-110 30)');
INSERT INTO test (geom) VALUES ('POINT(-109 29)');
INSERT INTO test (geom) VALUES ('POINT(0 49)');
```

Here is my .map file:

```
MAP
  IMAGETYPE      PNG
  EXTENT -115 25 -105 35
  SIZE           1024 512
  IMAGECOLOR     255 255 255
  CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "/usr/local/error.log"
  DEBUG 5
  LAYER
    NAME "test"
    CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
    CONNECTION "user=postgres dbname=postgres host=postgis"
    PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
    DATA "geom FROM test USING UNIQUE gid"
    STATUS ON
    TYPE POINT
    DEBUG 5
    CLASS
      Name "Red Points"
      STYLE
        COLOR 255 23 23
        SIZE 10
      END
    END
  END
END
```

I am generating the image using this call:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/test/test.map&layer=test&mode=map
```

and it comes back blank, but my expectation is to have 2 red points on it.

The logs don't have any errors. Here is the Mapserver log output:

```
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].732286 msPostGISLayerOpen: Got PostGIS version 20500.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].732297 msPostGISLayerOpen: Forcing 2D geometries: yes.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].732302 msPostGISLayerFreeItemInfo called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].732308 msPostGISLayerWhichShapes called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].732311 msPostGISParseData called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].732316 msPostGISParseData: unique_column=gid, srid=, geom_column_name=geom, table_name=test
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].732320 msPostGISBuildSQL called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].732323 msPostGISBuildSQLItems called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].732846 msPostGISBuildSQLItems: 0 items requested.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].732854 msPostGISBuildSQLFrom called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].732859 msPostGISBuildSQLWhere called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].732862 msPostGISBuildSQLSRID called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].732866 msPostGISBuildSQLSRID: Building find_srid line.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].732870 msPostGISBuildSQLBox called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].732906 msPostGISLayerWhichShapes query: select ST_AsBinary(ST_Force2D("geom"),'NDR') as geom,"gid"::text from test where "geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-120.009784735812 25,-120.009784735812 35,-99.9902152641879 35,-99.9902152641879 25,-120.009784735812 25))',find_srid('','test','geom'))
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755587 msPostGISLayerWhichShapes query status: PGRES_TUPLES_OK (2)
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755598 msPostGISLayerWhichShapes got 2 records in result.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755603 msPostGISLayerNextShape called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755606 msPostGISReadShape called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755844 msPostGISReadShape: Setting shape->index = 1
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755850 msPostGISReadShape: Setting shape->resultindex = 0
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755854 msPostGISReadShape: [index] 1
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755902 msPostGISReadShape: [shape] POINT (-110.0000000000000000 30.0000000000000000)
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755912 msPostGISLayerNextShape called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755915 msPostGISReadShape called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755918 msPostGISReadShape: Setting shape->index = 2
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755920 msPostGISReadShape: Setting shape->resultindex = 1
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755923 msPostGISReadShape: [index] 2
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755930 msPostGISReadShape: [shape] POINT (-109.0000000000000000 29.0000000000000000)
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755933 msPostGISLayerNextShape called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755936 msPostGISLayerFreeItemInfo called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].755939 msPostGISLayerClose called: geom FROM test USING UNIQUE gid
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].756175 msConnPoolRelease(test,user=postgres dbname=postgres host=postgis,0x7f2b26af2c60)
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].756182 msDrawMap(): Layer 0 (test), 0.080s
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].756189 msDrawMap(): Drawing Label Cache, 0.000s
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].756196 msDrawMap() total time: 0.082s
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].767146 msSaveImage(stdout) total time: 0.011s
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].767504 mapserv request processing time (msLoadMap not incl.): 0.093s
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].767534 msFreeMap(): freeing map at 0x561a6835b000.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].767569 freeLayer(): freeing layer at 0x7f2b22c44420.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].767591 msPostGISLayerIsOpen called.
[Mon Oct 22 20:30:35 2018].767649 msConnPoolClose(user=postgres dbname=postgres host=postgis,0x7f2b26af2c60)
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The issue here is the need to add SYMBOL to STYLE. The issue over there is where that SYMBOL is defined in reference to where it is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MapServer does not have a default symbol for points so you must define the symbol in your mapfile.

Include this in your mapfile

```
SYMBOL
  NAME "point"
  TYPE ELLIPSE
  POINTS
    1 1
  END
  FILLED TRUE
END
```

Then edit your STYLE

```
STYLE
    SYMBOL "point"
    COLOR 255 23 23
    SIZE 10
END
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I was assuming Mapserver has default STYLE for POINT.